# real time refreshing in processing

Tags: graphics, processing

I am new to processing, i found it by searching for "draw with coding" , and i tried it, seems every time i modify the code, i have to stop and render again to get the final result

Is there any way to get updated graph without re-rendering? that can be much more convenient for  creating simple figures. 
if not, is there any alternative to processing that can draw a graph with coding?

I've used Tikz in Latex, but that is just for Latex, I want something that can let me draw a figure by coding, I've suffered enough though using software like coreldraw, it lacks the fundamental elegance of coding..

thanks alot！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the [FluidForms libraries](http://fluidforms.eu/processing/fluid-forms-libs/).

- easy to setup
- documentation and video tutorials
- as long as you don't run into exceptions, live code comfortably
- if you prefix public variables with `param` you also get sliders for free :)

Do check out the video tutorials, especially [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=DzOZSMUwZjU):

[image: FluidFormsLibs live coding]

Also, if using Python isn't a problem I recommend having a look at:

1. [NodeBox](http://nodebox.net/)
2. [Field](http://openendedgroup.com/field/OverviewBanners2)

Python is a brilliant scripting language - which makes prototyping/'live coding' easy(although it can be compiled and it also plays nicely with c/c++) and is easy to pick up and a joy to use.

[image: Field preview]

Comment: Isn't FluidForms a 3d library? What does it have to do with live coding (i.e., seeing the results of changes in the code without relaunching the program)?

Comment: @JorgeCardoso You're right, it is a 3d library, but not just a 3d library, it also allows you to do live coding. You can see this in the linked video (which btw is on the library's website as previously linked)

Comment: Cool! Didn't know about the live coding capability!

Comment: @shelper FluidForms is a java library, so should work on Windows too and NodeBox runs on [Windows](http://nodebox.net/download/) too. I can confirm when I get access to a PC

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Nodebox 3 works on Windows,but that is not for coding based drawing, Nodebox 1 is only for MAC, which can be coded using python

Answer (score 0):

In Processing, you must re-run your program to see the changes (graphically), unless you write code to receive input from the user to dynamically adjust what you are drawing. For creating user interfaces there's for example the controlP5 library (http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/).

It doesn't support "live coding" (at least that I know of).

Answer (score 0):

You must re-run the code to see the new result.
If Live coding is what you're looking for, check out Fluxus (http://www.pawfal.org/fluxus/) or Impromptu (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impromptu_(programming_environment)